# Visualization of categorical variables (1D) with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a collection of categorical data and I'm trying to figure out how best to visualize it. It is a "simple" list (97 categories long) with just a name and an associated value. Here's a sample to work with (in the actual set, the names are much longer):

```
names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", 
"AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", 
"AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", 
"BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BK", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BP", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", 
"BU", "BV", "BW", "BX", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CF", "CG", "CH", 
"CI", "CJ", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CP", "CQ", "CR", "CS")

cts <- c(620, 343, 165, 121, 107, 106, 104, 88, 83, 59, 57, 56, 49, 45, 44, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 35, 31, 31, 29, 27, 24, 23, 23, 22, 21, 21, 20, 20, 17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 
15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

testdat <- data.frame(names, cts)
```

My initial thought was to make a lollipop chart, but because there are so many points, R squishes them all together and it becomes a mess. Bar/column charts are out for the same reason. I thought it might be possible to make a plot in which all of the categories have a shape (a box?) with an area that corresponds to the `cts` variable, but I haven't found anything like that (I tried the `waffle` package, but I'm struggling with it). Everything that I've found seems to require at least two numerical values to plot in an x vs y way.

My next data set is in the same format, only with many more categories (9,351 instead of "just" 97), so I'm hoping for something I could expand.

Anyone have ideas on how to look at this data without cutting it up?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a treemap?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)

ggplot(testdat, aes(area = cts, fill = names)) +
    geom_treemap() +
    geom_treemap_text(aes(label = names), place = 'center') +
    scale_fill_discrete(guide = 'none', limits = sample(testdat$names))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how I see this extending to the "big" data set... but it is cool.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here. One is that a plot with 100 labelled categories is always going to be too busy. It might be better to plot the sorted values on a numeric axis, and label some important illustrative categories:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(1) 

plot_dat <- testdat %>%
  arrange(cts) %>%
  mutate(num = seq(nrow(.)))

  ggplot(plot_dat, aes(num, cts)) +
  geom_point(colour = "deepskyblue4") +
  geom_label_repel(data = plot_dat[sample(nrow(plot_dat), 5), ],
                   aes(label = names), nudge_y = 0.5) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Ordered cts values (log scale)") +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

The other problem is filling 2d space with 1d information. You can do this with a treemap, or with packing circles:

```r
library(packcircles)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

testdat <- cbind(testdat, circleRepelLayout(testdat$cts)$layout)

ggplot(testdat, aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, fill = radius)) +
  geom_circle(aes(r = radius)) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = names, size = order(radius))) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Pastel1") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Or just a waffle where the colours represent values:

```r
library(tidyverse)

testdat %>%
  mutate(x = rep(1:10, each = 10)[seq(nrow(.))],
         y = rep(1:10, 10)[seq(nrow(.))]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = log(cts))) +
  geom_tile(width = 0.8, height = 0.8) +
  geom_text(aes(label = names), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "E") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Especially the waffle plot. I like it!

Comment: I like these quite a bit. The packed circles certainly might work - and might even be extendable to the bigger data set. I will try it!

Comment: Because the original names were so long, maybe I could use the letters to make the legend. How would I do that?

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg just change `fill = radius` to `fill = names` and  remove `legend.position = "none"` You will need to change the fill scale too. However, there is no way a viewer will be able to match 100 colours to 100 labels via a legend. Also, the legend will be huge.

Comment: Agreed. Not an easy problem - especially when it gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach:

Use a barchart with log transformed axis:

```
library(tidyverse)

testdat %>% 
  mutate(names = factor(names, levels = names)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = names, y=log(cts), fill= log(cts)))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This will never be readable - which is part of the problem.

Comment: It depends on how you define readable. This is a very simple plot with many information about your data.

Comment: I didn't mean to dismiss this out of hand, but there are really two issues. First, the letters used here were made up to take the place of much longer names. Even if you turn those names 90 degrees, with so many, they will be so small, it will be impossible to read. Secondly, the goal is to extend this to a much larger data set (see original post); if this is extended to 2000+ names, it will be microscopic.

Comment: I see and agree.